# Why won't WebPositive open again after I close it, and how do I fix it?

Tags: browser, haiku

I'm running Haiku from a USB stick. I opened up the web browser, WebPositive, and tested to see if I could load anything. It didn't, so I closed it. Then I realized - duh, I wasn't connected to the Internet. So I put the password to the WiFi in, and tried to open WebPositive. It wouldn't open. FWIW, it sort of shows as being open on the bar, but it won't go to it when I click. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I have no idea why this particular application may have trouble closing (could be the application itself, or related to being on usb, or not having internet when opened causing some issues due to poor coding etc), it should be possible to kill it from the command line. You can then try it again once the WiFi is connected.

Instructions from http://betips.net/1997/09/09/kill-rogue-apps/ say:

> If apps hang and either won’t go away or are interrupting other apps, open up Terminal, and type `ps`.
>   This will display a list of all running processes. Each process has an associated ID# at the left of the screen. Type `kill 123` [where 123 is the ID of the app that’s misbehaving] and it will die. If it doesn’t die, try the super killer: `kill 123 -9`